# Flask-Email, process stalls on nonexistent email

Tags: python, email, flask

I tracked down a bug where if a user registers with a bad email address (as in non-deliverable, no future email's will go out until the process is rebooting (gunicorn since its on a web server).

The actual code is fine, but I will provide anyway.

```
from .decorators import async
def send_email(to, subject, template):
    msg = Message(
        subject, 
        recipients=[to],
        html = template,
        sender = app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER']
    )


@async
def send_async_email(app, msg):
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)


    token = generate_confirmation_token(user.email)
    html = render_template('user/activate.html', token=token, _external=True)
    subject = "Please confirm your email"
    email = user.email
    send_email(email, subject, html)
    #mail.send(msg)
    send_async_email(app, msg)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't your recursive calls to `send_async_email`?

Comment: @dirn it works until someone sends an undeliverable email. So i think not. It may be a problem on send grid's side, which is what I am using to deliver.

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with send grid. I fixed it by using their API's instead of using a smtp relay.